# Missing function: Seperate in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have my function missing with the correct code. Do you know the root cause? Here is the error

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "a.b", "a.d", "b.c"))
df %>% separate(x, c("A", "B"))
```

> Error in UseMethod("separate") :    no applicable method for
>   'separate' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Comment: Without seeing any code, no, we don't know the root cause of the error.  Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get better results.

Answer (score 1):

separate is a function from the `tidyr` package not the `dplyr` package.

use `library(tidyr)` or `tidyr::separate` instead.